# Optimisation of code to improve memory and speed

Tags: java, for-loop, new-operator

I am looking to speed this up specifically around obtaining the minutes and setting the markers. In what ways can i can improve the memory usage and speed?

I have tried the below code

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 24; i++) {

    final Minute min = new Minute(0, i, 28, 04, 2019);
    final Minute min1 = new Minute(30, i, 28, 04, 2019);
    final Marker currentEnd = new ValueMarker((double) min.getFirstMillisecond());
    final Marker currentEnd1 = new ValueMarker((double) min1.getFirstMillisecond());

    currentEnd1.setLabel("HH" + ((i * 2) - 1 + 3));
    currentEnd.setLabel("HH" + ((i * 2) - 2 + 3));

    currentEnd.setLabelAnchor(RectangleAnchor.TOP);
    currentEnd.setLabelFont(font3);
    currentEnd.setLabelTextAnchor(TextAnchor.TOP_LEFT);
    currentEnd1.setLabelAnchor(RectangleAnchor.TOP);
    currentEnd1.setLabelFont(font3);
    currentEnd1.setLabelTextAnchor(TextAnchor.TOP_LEFT);
    currentEnd.setPaint(Color.red);
    currentEnd1.setPaint(Color.red);
    plot1.addDomainMarker(currentEnd1);
    plot1.addDomainMarker(currentEnd);

}
```

Comment: Assuming that this is related to, http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html , the posted code is almost certainly *not* the bottleneck. How often is this code called, and how long does it take?

Comment: As an aside: don't prefix integer literals with `0` unless you *really* mean to use octal (you're lucky you're not writing this code in August).

Comment: Yes thats right it is linked to JFreeChart, i call it on a scheduled execution every 5 mins. I have profiled the code and the coloring and setting anchors also increase the heap. But the creation of new Minutes appear to also be a drain

Comment: so in other words you just need to increment by ( the number of milliseconds in 30 minutes ). if only there were a way to compute that in advance... hint, hint

Comment: Do you mean create the values at run time?